# Linux distribution on Inspiron N5110?

Tags: laptop, download

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110, and I would like to install a Linux distribution(Ubuntu, Arch, etc) on this laptop. However, I'm not sure which one I should install. I googled this question, and others say that Archlinux and Ubuntu Linux are preferable, but on [enter link description here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19442470), it says that Ubuntu Linux on the Inspiron N5110 causes the fan to stop turning while booting(or maybe they are just describing the Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit). Does someone know of a distribution and its version that won't cause the fan to stop.

Comment: You want Ubuntu.

Comment: Would the fan stop turning, or is the moderator just referring to the windows ultimate?

Comment: That thread is *five years old*; the kernel has evolved significantly since then. You will be fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 was released in 2012. Just pick a version that starts with 17 and install it.

Comment: So any that starts with 17 will work and won't cause overheating or other problems? @jasonwryan

Comment: No, it is likely to cause your machine to explode, causing shrapnel to obliterate everything in a 3m radius. STOP @'ing me.

Comment: Maybe in bios are settings to turn on/off fullspeed of fan during POST? In some desktop it is. And maybe described situation is only settings not incapability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that they are talking about windows 7 ultimate when they complain about the fan not working.

And like Jasonwryan said the thread is pretty old. So ubuntu should work. Arch Is harder to setup so I suggest you first try ubuntu and get used to linux, before you try out Arch.

Comment: Do you know which version works best? @TheAnonymousSpy

Comment: Assuming your are asking wich version  of ubuntu, you can either go for 17.04, latest release, or 16.04, which has long term support.

Comment: I would personally go for 17.04 for the latest features